# How to instantiate a static vector of object?

Tags: c++, instantiation, static-members

I have a class A, which has a static vector of objects. The objects are of class B

```
class A {
  public:
    static void InstantiateVector();
  private:
    static vector<B> vector_of_B;
}
```

In function InstantiateVector()

```
for (i=0; i < 5; i++) {
  B b = B();
  vector<B>.push_back(b);
}
```

But I have compilation error using visual studio 2008: unresolved external symbol...
Is it possible to instantiate static vector using above method? For object b to be created, some data has to be read from input file, and stored as member variables of b

Or it is not possible, and only simple static vector is possible? I read somewhere that to instantiate static vector, you must first define a const int a[] = {1,2,3}, and then copy a[] into vector

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to provide the definition of `vector_of_b` as follows:

```
// A.h
class A {
  public:
    static void InstantiateVector();
  private:
    static vector<B> vector_of_B;
};

// A.cpp
// defining it fixes the unresolved external:
vector<B> A::vector_of_B;
```

As a side note, your `InstantiateVector()` makes a lot of unnecessary copies that may (or may not) be optimized away.

```
vector_of_B.reserve(5);  // will prevent the need to reallocate the underlying
                         // buffer if you plan on storing 5 (and only 5) objects
for (i=0; i < 5; i++) {
  vector_of_B.push_back(B());
}
```

In fact, for this simple example where you are just default constructing `B` objects, the most concise way of doing this is simply to replace the loop all together with:

```
// default constructs 5 B objects into the vector
vector_of_B.resize(5);
```

Comment: can you explain more about your side note? I am purposely creating static objects of B, as I assume that its memory will automatically be freed on the end of the program?

Comment: Re the extra copies: who cares?  The code will only be executed once.

Comment: @JamesKanze in this particular instance, yes.  The code (may) only be run once, but if its indicative of other parts of the code then its just something to point out.

Comment: @Michael Yes you are creating static objects of B and they will be deleted at the end of the program, but your function as written has at least two copies of each `B` object (one for initialization, and one (or more) for the vector insert).

Comment: oic, then will it be better to declare a vector of pointers to B? vector<B*> vector_of_B

Comment: No -- see my suggestion for (in my opinion) the most appropriate way to accomplish.

Comment: How about just `vector_of_B.resize(5);` to get 5 default-constructed elements?

Comment: @FredOverflow great suggestion, better than my answer's example.

Answer (score 4):

Add the *definition* of the static member object to your class implementation file:

```
#include "A.h"

std::vector<B> A::vector_of_B;
```

Or rather, absorbing and obviating the initialization routine:

```
std::vector<B> A::vector_of_B(5, B()); // same effect as `A::InstantiateVector()`
```

<sub>Note: In C++98/03, `vector_of_B(5)` and `vector_of_B(5, B())` are identical. In C++11 they're not.</sub>

Comment: "In C++11 they're not."  In C++11, how do they differ?

Comment: @Rob: In C++11, the former value-initializes the new elements, the latter direct-initializes them to a copy of `B()`. In C++98/03 both versions have the second behaviour. It was an oversight of the old standard that value-initialization wasn't possible, though it clearly should have been. Same goes for `resize()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a static helper or use boost::assign

1>using a small helper:

```
#include <boost\assign.hpp>
class B{};

class A {
 public:
    static bool m_helper;
    static bool InstantiateVector()
    {
        for (int i=0; i < 5; ++i) 
        {
            B b;
            vector_of_B.push_back(b);
        }
        return true;
    }
private:
    static vector<B> vector_of_B;
};

bool A::m_helper = InstantiateVector();//helper help initialize static vector here
```

2> Use boost::assign which is eaiser, one line is enough:

```
vector<B> A::vector_of_B = boost::assign::list_of(B())(B())(B())(B())(B());
```