# C++ static vector of objects inside Object contstructor access?

Tags: c++, pointers, object, vector, static

I want a static vector inside Object that stores pointers to every Object ever constructed so I can run a loop through every Object.

```
//Object.h
public:
  Object();
  stuff();
  static vector<Object*> objects;

//Object.cpp
vector<Object*> Object::objects;
Object::Object(){ objects.push_back(this); }
Object::stuff(){ /*Do stuff*/ }
```

[Is this correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531981/how-to-instantiate-a-static-vector-of-object/)

I want this to work:

```
//ObjectB.cpp
Object::objects[0]->stuff();
```

When I run it, I'm getting "Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC" error.

Comment: You have posted bits and pieces of your code. An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Object.h:

```
#ifndef OBJECT_H
#define OBJECT_H

#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Object {
public:
  Object();
  void stuff();
  static vector<Object*> objects;
};

#endif // OBJECT_H
```

Object.cpp:

```
#include "Object.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector<Object*> Object::objects;

Object::Object() {
  objects.push_back(this);
}

void Object::stuff() {
  cout << "Stuff from object" << endl;
}
```

ObjectB.cpp:

```
#include "Object.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  Object a,b,c;

  // this loop should run 3 times, as many as Object instance created
  for (vector<Object*>::iterator it = Object::objects.begin(); it != Object::objects.end(); it++) {
    (*it)->stuff();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: Well, without it i'm getting "unresolved external symbol" compiling error.

Comment: If each of the file is not big (say max. 20 lines) you can post all the contents, plus the command you use to compile it. Otherwise, an easy to access link might be OK. I can barely see the cause of the problem. C/C++ is quite primitive in regard to modular programming, so the compiler cannot automatically resolve interlinked symbols without us providing the them correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "ObjectB" class inherits the "Object" class, your Object.h and Object.cpp are OK.

```
// Object.h
static vector<Object*> objects; // [Is this correct?][1]
```

-> OK, static member declaration

```
// Object.cpp
vector<Object*> Object::objects; // [Is this correct?][1]
```

-> OK, static member initialisation (in your cpp file)

```
// Object.h
vector<Object*> Object::objects; //[error C2838][2]
```

-> This is not right, I assume ObjectB inherits Object, you don't have to declare that. To refer to your static member, you just have to do "Object::objects". Do not forget to call your Object constructor from your ObjectB constructor, otherwise your ObjectB instance will not be added to your Object::objects vector :

```
// ObjectB.cpp
ObjectB() : Object() // Calling Object() will add your instance to "objects" vector
{
  ...
}
```

Then :

```
Object::objects.stuff(); // or with ->, i.e. Object::objects->stuff()
```

-> This should work (if you do not forget to call Object constructor from your ObjectB constructor).

To the question "is there another way to keep track of all your objects", well, it depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't want it to inherit anything. I want to be able to loop through every Object and run a member function.

Comment: But you cannot put your ObjectB instance in your "objects" vector if ObjectB does not inherit Object (because it is a vector of "Object"). Do you want to store your ObjectB instances in a different vector ? (Maybe I misunderstood something here, do you have an ObjectB class ? Or ObjectB.cpp does contains Object class implementation ?)