# c++ How to get size of vector with struct type

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I'm having trouble getting the size of a vector with struct types in it.
apples.h:

```
#ifndef APPLES_H
#define APPLES_H
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct a{
    int b;
    bool c;
};

class apples
{
    public:
        apples();
        ~apples();
    protected:
    private:


        static std::vector<a> d;

};

#endif // APPLES_H
```

apples.cpp:

```
#include "apples.h"

std::vector<a> d;

apples::apples()
{
    std::cout<<d.size()<<std::endl;
}

apples::~apples()
{
    //dtor
}
```

this code gives me "undefined reference to 'apples:d'"
the main.cpp doesnt even call include the apples class so I dont see a point posting it

Comment: Here's further explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531981/how-to-instantiate-a-static-vector-of-object

Answer (score 1):

Your `std::vector<a> d;` is missing the class name in front of `d`. This should fix your error:

```
std::vector<a> apples::d;
```

Otherwise the compiler can't know that's the definition of the `d` in `apples`.